# Strange Android.view.InfalteException

Tags: android, layout

Hi I developed a little app that consists on a dashboard that send you to some different simple screens. And I'm facing a strange problem, I open the app on the dashboard I select a random screen to cast. press back select a second random option like "contact us" and on the third options it always crash no matter the sequence of menu buttons I went through.

The dashBoard.java class is as simple as 10 buttons with their respective intents that send you to other basic screens.

The dashboard.java is as follows:

```
public class DashBoardActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button soportebt, beneficiosbt, faqbt, twtbt, facebt;
        Button contactobt;
        Button cajerosbt;
        Button consultacuentabt;
        Button indicadoresfinancierosbt;
        Button promocionesbt;
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

        //inicializar variables de botones
        faqbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.faqbtm);
        facebt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twtbtm);
        beneficiosbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.beneficiosbtm);
        twtbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.facebtm);
        soportebt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.soportebtm);
        contactobt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contactobtm);
        cajerosbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cajerobtm);
        consultacuentabt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.consultabtm);
        indicadoresfinancierosbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.indicadoresbtm);
        promocionesbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.promobtm);

        //click de las variables
        faqbt.setOnClickListener(this);
        beneficiosbt.setOnClickListener(this);
        facebt.setOnClickListener(this);
        twtbt.setOnClickListener(this);
        soportebt.setOnClickListener(this);
        contactobt.setOnClickListener(this);
        promocionesbt.setOnClickListener(this);
        cajerosbt.setOnClickListener(this);
        consultacuentabt.setOnClickListener(this);
        indicadoresfinancierosbt.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.faqbtm:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FAQ.class);
            startActivity(intent);      
            break;
        case R.id.facebtm:
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/KetanoLab") ) );
            break;
        case R.id.twtbtm:
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/#!/KetanoLab") ) );
            break;
        case R.id.soportebtm:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), soporte.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            break;
        case R.id.consultabtm:
            Intent intent7 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), consultacuenta.class);
            startActivity(intent7);
            break;
        case R.id.beneficiosbtm:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), beneficios.class);
            startActivity(intent2); 
            break;
        case R.id.contactobtm:
            Intent intent4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), contacto.class);
            startActivity(intent4); 
            break;
        case R.id.cajerobtm:
            Intent intent6 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cajeros.class);
            startActivity(intent6);
            break;
        case R.id.indicadoresbtm:
            Intent intent8 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), indicadoresFinancieros.class);
            startActivity(intent8);
            break;
        case R.id.promobtm:
            Intent intent5 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), promo.class);
            startActivity(intent5);
            break;

        }

    }
}
```

The layout mainmenu.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bacoprin"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/twtbtm"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/facebtm"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/tww"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/facebtm"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/face"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/faqbtm"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/promobtm"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btnfaq"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/promobtm"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/indicadoresbtm"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btnpromo"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/beneficiosbtm"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/consultabtm"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btnbeneficios"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/consultabtm"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/cajerobtm"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btnconsulta"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/indicadoresbtm"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/contactobtm"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btnindicadores"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cajerobtm"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/contactobtm"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btncajeros"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contactobtm"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btncontacto"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/soportebtm"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btnemergencias"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Each drawable of the buttons on the dasboard has this structure:

btnconsulta.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/consulta" />    
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/consultaapre" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/consulta" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/consulta" />
</selector>
```

The logCat that shows the problem occur

```
10-05 10:01:29.490: D/ViewRootImpl(2621): Action[0] ID[0] Pos[105.92644,783.9985]
10-05 10:01:29.550: D/ViewRootImpl(2621): Action[1] ID[0] Pos[99.9306,794.9942]
10-05 10:02:02.100: I/dalvikvm-heap(2866): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.717MB for 3075856-byte allocation
10-05 10:02:02.170: D/dalvikvm(2866): GC_CONCURRENT freed 88K, 7% free 15725K/16811K, paused 4ms+2ms
10-05 10:02:02.230: I/dalvikvm-heap(2866): Grow heap (frag case) to 32.480MB for 12303376-byte allocation
10-05 10:02:02.270: D/dalvikvm(2866): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 27739K/28847K, paused 5ms+2ms
10-05 10:02:02.500: I/dalvikvm-heap(2866): Grow heap (frag case) to 39.008MB for 309040-byte allocation
10-05 10:02:02.540: D/dalvikvm(2866): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4008K, 14% free 29130K/33711K, paused 2ms+2ms
10-05 10:02:18.010: D/ViewRootImpl(2866): Action[0] ID[0] Pos[151.39487,858.96924]
10-05 10:02:18.090: D/ViewRootImpl(2866): Action[1] ID[0] Pos[153.89313,865.4667]
10-05 10:02:19.050: D/ViewRootImpl(2866): Action[0] ID[0] Pos[181.37404,771.0036]
10-05 10:02:19.140: D/ViewRootImpl(2866): Action[1] ID[0] Pos[183.37265,777.0012]
10-05 10:02:19.190: I/dalvikvm-heap(2866): Grow heap (frag case) to 41.742MB for 4292480-byte allocation
10-05 10:02:19.240: D/dalvikvm(2866): GC_CONCURRENT freed 396K, 10% free 34488K/37935K, paused 2ms+2ms
10-05 10:02:19.260: I/dalvikvm-heap(2866): Grow heap (frag case) to 48.628MB for 7627300-byte allocation
10-05 10:02:19.300: D/dalvikvm(2866): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 8% free 41933K/45423K, paused 2ms+3ms
10-05 10:02:21.080: D/ViewRootImpl(2866): Action[0] ID[0] Pos[223.84454,932.9403]
10-05 10:02:21.180: D/ViewRootImpl(2866): Action[1] ID[0] Pos[222.3456,937.43854]
10-05 10:02:21.300: I/dalvikvm-heap(2866): Grow heap (frag case) to 54.425MB for 3075856-byte allocation
10-05 10:02:21.360: I/dalvikvm-heap(2866): Clamp target GC heap from 66.160MB to 64.000MB
10-05 10:02:21.360: I/dalvikvm-heap(2866): Grow heap (frag case) to 64.000MB for 12303376-byte allocation
10-05 10:02:21.380: D/dalvikvm(2866): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4786K, 13% free 55102K/62767K, paused 2ms+4ms
10-05 10:02:22.650: D/ViewRootImpl(2866): Action[0] ID[0] Pos[199.8612,1071.8861]
10-05 10:02:22.720: D/ViewRootImpl(2866): Action[1] ID[0] Pos[199.36156,1073.3855]
10-05 10:02:22.840: I/dalvikvm-heap(2866): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 12303376-byte allocation
10-05 10:02:22.860: D/dalvikvm(2866): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 12808K, 28% free 45325K/62767K, paused 21ms
10-05 10:02:22.900: D/dalvikvm(2866): GC_CONCURRENT freed 12029K, 28% free 45311K/62767K, paused 2ms+3ms
10-05 10:02:24.370: D/ViewRootImpl(2866): Action[0] ID[0] Pos[204.35808,1217.3293]
10-05 10:02:24.480: D/ViewRootImpl(2866): Action[1] ID[0] Pos[208.3553,1217.3293]
10-05 10:02:24.610: I/dalvikvm-heap(2866): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 12303376-byte allocation
10-05 10:02:24.640: D/dalvikvm(2866): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 3021K, 28% free 45357K/62767K, paused 23ms
10-05 10:02:24.640: E/dalvikvm-heap(2866): Out of memory on a 12303376-byte allocation.
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40c0f460 self=0x1e0fa58
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   | sysTid=2866 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1074357512
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   | schedstat=( 2316137000 607448000 1407 ) utm=205 stm=26 core=0
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2798)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:385)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:174)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:170)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:252)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1888)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at com.ketanolab.banca.movil.generico.soporte.onCreate(soporte.java:32)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4518)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1924)
10-05 10:02:24.640: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1985)
10-05 10:02:24.650: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-05 10:02:24.650: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
10-05 10:02:24.650: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 10:02:24.650: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-05 10:02:24.650: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4493)
10-05 10:02:24.650: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 10:02:24.650: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-05 10:02:24.650: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
10-05 10:02:24.650: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
10-05 10:02:24.650: I/dalvikvm(2866):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 10:02:24.650: D/AndroidRuntime(2866): Shutting down VM
10-05 10:02:24.650: W/dalvikvm(2866): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c0e1f8)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ketanolab.banca.movil.generico/com.ketanolab.banca.movil.generico.soporte}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1960)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1985)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4493)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:252)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1888)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at com.ketanolab.banca.movil.generico.soporte.onCreate(soporte.java:32)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4518)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1924)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     ... 11 more
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     ... 23 more
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2798)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:385)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:174)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:170)
10-05 10:02:24.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     ... 26 more
```

Note: for the images: each View background image is 40kb and each of the two images of a button is 9kb size.

The strange think if you look at the logcat is that before crashing the memory allocated grows exponentially. Also an strangethink is that crashed more quickly on my lg 4x HD that has 1gb ram than on my old x10 mini that is using cm7.1 port .

any ideas on how to work arround this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Edit1: Using DDMS heap update I saw that is allocationg more less 45.000 objects after to screens no matter wich ones. so I guess is a Heap problem

Edit: for those who want to see the support class xml file is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoemergencia"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lostcardbtn"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:background="@layout/btnstandar"
        android:text="@string/emergencia_lostcardbtn_txt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/callpolicebtn"
               android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:background="@layout/btnstandar"
        android:text="@string/emergencia_callpolicebtn_txt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/callhospitalbtn"
               android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:background="@layout/btnstandar"
        android:text="@string/emergencia_callhospitalbtn_txt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the stacktrace mentions a linearlayout. are you sure this is it ?

Comment: the problem is in the soporte class, not the one you posted

Comment: "Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>" This means that the XML file you are trying to inflate, at line 2 doesn't recognize the class of the View item you are trying to show.

Comment: yes, to make the app crash I pressed a button of the menu, then came back, pressed another button of the menu. the came back and on the third it crashes no matter the order of buttons. so in this case it came to a linear layout of the other view. but if this view is the first I go to it doesn't crash

Comment: ALso, I'm adding the support.class xml file for those who want to see it

Comment: the first exception shown in the stack trace says out of memory trying to create the drawable from resources. i would look at the drawable you have referenced in the btnconsulta.xml file and see if its large. if you are loading it 10 times, it might cause problems

Comment: the 2 drawables on the btnconsulta.xml selector are 9kb